# Is this sequence is increasing or decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis

I have this sequence  $$u_n=(\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}-\frac{1}{2n+1})$$

is it increasing or decreasing ?

Thank you

I found  $u_{n+1}-u_n=-\frac{3}{8.2^n}+\frac{2}{(2n+3)(2n+1)}$

Comment: Rate of increase/decrease of exponential function is greater and that will drive the overall increasing or decreasing nature here.

Comment: though here exponential is in the denominator

Comment: @J.W.Tanner That's why the overall sequence should be decreasing.

Comment: @gemspark:  isn't $\color{red}-\dfrac1{2n+1}$ increasing?

Comment: I agree it is increasing and I guess I may have been looking it the wrong way. Correct answer is written below.

Answer (score 1):

$u_{n} - u_{n-1} = \dfrac{1}{2^{2n+1}} - \dfrac{1}{2^{2n-1}} + \dfrac{1}{2n-1}-\dfrac{1}{2n+1} = \dfrac{2}{4n^2-1}-\dfrac{3}{2^{2n+1}}$

Now $$\dfrac{2}{4n^2-1}-\dfrac{3}{2^{2n+1}} \ge 0 \iff 4^{n+1}\ge 3(4n^2-1)$$ which is true. You may prove it by induction f.e.

Comment: how to prove that for n+1 it is right ?